# Can this responsive-table JS code be made more performant?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a working [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kydjewn2/)

I'm just wondering if there's anything I should do to improve performance of my code?

I was using dataTables.net's responsive plugin before this, and am happy to say that my (much simpler) code runs about 5 times quicker than that did.  On my machine the fiddle averages about 50ms versus 250ms if I use DT responsive.

But can it be made better?  I'm FAR from a JS expert, as I'm sure it shows.  I'm very happy to drop jQuery if it can be done better without!

```
function initResponsiveTables() {
    //does this enhance performance at all?
    'use strict';

    //get an array of <th> elements
    var th = $('th');

    //initialise in top scope
    var priorities = [];

    //iterate over the <th>s, extracting their column priorities
    th.each(function (index) {
        var priority = th[index].getAttribute('data-priority');

        //TODO: this seems very messy, I feel there must be a cleaner way?
        if (priorities[priority] === undefined) {
            priorities[priority] = index;
        } else {
            priorities[priority] += ',' + index;
        }
    });

    //clean up the array so we have consecutive indices
    priorities = priorities.filter(function (x) {
        return x !== undefined && x !== null;
    });

    //initialise all of these outside of the loop
    var sCols = '';
    var aCols = [];
    var aSelectors = [];
    var sSelectors = '';
    var i;

    //while the table is wider than the window, and there's still columns to remove
    while ($('#table').width() > $(window).width() - 40 && priorities.length > 0) {
        //get the lowest priority
        sCols = (priorities.pop() + '');

        //split it, in case we have more than one column on the same priority
        //in this case we prefer to remove them as a group, rather than one at a time
        aCols = sCols.split(',');

        //clear the array from previous iteration
        aSelectors = [];
        for (i = 0; i < aCols.length; i++) {
            //build up the jQuery selectors
            aSelectors.push('td:nth-child(' + aCols[i] + '), th:nth-child(' + aCols[i] + ')');
        }

        //make jQuery selector string
        sSelectors = aSelectors.join(', ');

        //hide relevant columns
        $(sSelectors).css('display', 'none');
    }
}

var start = performance.now();;

initResponsiveTables();

alert(performance.now() - start);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question would be better placed in the [code review community](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I had no idea such a community existed @Tarekis, thanks!  Can I leave it here too or do I need to choose one or the other?

Comment: In my opinion it would be advisable to move your question to the other community and delete it on SO, if the code review community will not respond, you might try again here, but proper usage of communities is essential to keep Stack Exchange organized.

Comment: @Tarekis Code Review always responds.

Comment: @Mast Response to a question always bases on the question itself, but i see you think a great deal of Code Review, OP will surely move it happily now ;)

Comment: There are enough JS/jQuery regulars around there to get this answered, so yea, this can 'happily' be moved.